# How do you call top block with user info on a profile screen?

Tags: terminology, ux-designer, frontend-development, design-system

There is this block in every social media app, on a user profile screen. It contains user's userpic, name and other info, before their content starts below it.

How do UX designers and developers call this block as a component in their design system?

[image]

Comment: I would go with "Profile overview" or "User overview"

Answer (score 2):

I often see these called "Profile Cards":

https://www.vic.gov.au/profile-card

http://designsystem.servicenow.com/#!/components/profile-cards

Answer (score 1):

This section is normally called 'Profile Header'.

Comment: @Wanda Well apparently, everyone else thinks the same as I do.

Comment: I wanted to add that you should elaborate your answer with examples, but I ended up posting a rather vague (and tbh kind of rude) auto-reply.